# Отображение и сохранение данных формы в виде изображения

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5, php

Добрый день, поставили сложную задачу, поэтому решил попросить помощи тут.

[image]

На скриншоте показана блок-схема, которая должна получиться в конечном итоге. Слева в формы вводим данные, а справа на рисунке эти данные отображаются.

Что мне лучше использовать: HTML5 + Canvas + JavaScript или PHP + GD2 или ImageMagick? Также буду очень рад, если вы предложите ваше решение. Результат (картинку) нужно в конце сохранить на сервере, желательно в файле с расширением .TIFF.

Comment: Во-первых, вы путаете "право" и "лево", во-вторых, готовое решение вам никто не предоставит.

Для реализации, по-моему, лучше всего использовать `HTML5 + Canvas + JavaScript`, только возникнут проблемы с кроссбраузерностью. Но для сохранения результата без `PHP` не обойтись.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день. HTML5 + Canvas + JavaScript - хороший выбор, но могу еще посоветовать nodejs, [socket.io](http://socket.io) и imagemagick, для асинхронности и красоты так сказать. Или принципиально на сервере php?

Comment: Нет, не принципиально конечно, но с node.js нужно разбираться с нуля, а с php я уже знаком!

Comment: Если не хотите изучать node (а зря :)), то конечно html5 + canvas + js + websockets + php

Comment: Если Вы можете дать ссылку (желательно на русском) по node.js, canvas и websocket, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Я конечно понимаю, что читать на русском более комфортно, но коли уж связались с программированием, знать технический английский все таки стоит. Просто вы не найдете нужного количества информации на русском ;) вот пример node.js & websockets - http://martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial. Еще, дабы упростить себе жизнь - expressjs.com. 
С уважением.

Answer (score 1):

Можно на Flash сделать. Старо, но при грамотной связке с js работать будет без проблем и реализуется довольно просто